# Adding the ORDER BY has broken my function. How do I order it?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

```
function showSearchResults()
{

$keyword = $_POST['keyword'];

    $q = "SELECT * FROM user_info INNER JOIN project ON user_info.user_id = project.user_id 
    LEFT JOIN bedsize ON project.bedsize_fk = bedsize.bedsize_id 
    LEFT JOIN topics_of_improv ON project.p_id = topics_of_improv.p_id 
    LEFT JOIN medication ON topics_of_improv.medication_fk = medication.med_id 
    LEFT JOIN care_trans ON topics_of_improv.care_trans_fk = care_trans.care_trans_id 
    LEFT JOIN hosp_acquired_infect ON topics_of_improv.hosp_acquired_infect_fk = hosp_acquired_infect.hai_id 
    LEFT JOIN hosp_patient_care_pro ON topics_of_improv.hosp_patient_care_pro_fk = hosp_patient_care_pro.hpcp_id 
    LEFT JOIN health_it ON topics_of_improv.health_it_fk = health_it.health_it_id 
    LEFT JOIN teamwork ON topics_of_improv.teamwork_fk = teamwork.teamwork_id 
    LEFT JOIN project_diss ON topics_of_improv.project_diss_fk = project_diss.project_diss_id 
    LEFT JOIN resources ON topics_of_improv.resources_fk = resources.resources_id LEFT JOIN summary ON project.p_id = summary.p_id 
    LEFT JOIN process ON summary.process_fk = process.process_id 
    WHERE (project.description LIKE '%" . $keyword . "%' 
    OR summary.improvement LIKE '%" . $keyword . "%'  
    OR summary.interventions  LIKE '%" . $keyword . "%' 
    OR summary.brief LIKE '%" . $keyword . "%' 
    OR summary.lessons LIKE '%" . $keyword . "%' 
    OR summary.actions LIKE '%" . $keyword . "%' 
    OR summary.measures LIKE '%" . $keyword . "%' 
    OR summary.clinical LIKE '%" . $keyword . "%') 
    ORDER BY project.p_id DESC";

    @$type = $_POST['type'];
    @$state = $_POST['state'];
    @$bedsize = $_POST['bedsize'];
    @$care_trans = $_POST['care_trans'];
    @$health_it = $_POST['health_it'];
    @$hai = $_POST['hai'];
    @$hpcp = $_POST['hpcp'];
    @$medication = $_POST['medication'];
    @$process = $_POST['process'];
    @$project_diss = $_POST['pro_diss'];
    @$resources = $_POST['resources'];
    @$teamwork = $_POST['teamwork'];

    $uid = $_SESSION['userid'];

        if ($_SESSION['level'] == '0') 
        //$q .= "AND project.approved = 'yes' ";

        //if($uid)
        //$q .= "AND project.user_id = '".$uid."' ";

        if($uid)
        $q .= "AND project.user_id = '".$uid."' OR project.approved = 'yes'";

        if($type)
        $q .= " AND project.type = '".$type."' ";

        if($state)
        $q .= " AND project.p_state = '".$state."' ";

        if($bedsize)
        $q .= " AND bedsize.bedsize_id = '".$bedsize."' ";

        if($care_trans)
        $q .= " AND care_trans.care_trans_id = '".$care_trans."' ";

        if($health_it)
        $q .= " AND health_it.health_it_id = '".$health_it."' ";

        if($hai)
        $q .= " AND hosp_acquired_infect.hai_id = '".$hai."' ";

        if($hpcp)
        $q .= " AND hosp_patient_care_pro.hpcp_id = '".$hpcp."' ";

        if($medication)
        $q .= " AND medication.med_id = '".$medication."' ";

        if($process)
        $q .= " AND project.p_state = '".$process."' ";

        if($project_diss)
        $q .= " AND project_diss.project_diss_id = '".$project_diss."' ";

        if($resources)
        $q .= " AND resources.resources_id = '".$resources."' ";

        if($teamwork)
        $q .= " AND teamwork.teamwork_id = '".$teamwork."' ";


        $result = mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());

        if(mysql_num_rows($result)==0){
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>No records matched your search criteria</td>";
            echo "<td></td>";
            echo "<td><a href='advanced_search.php'>Please click here to try again</a></td>";
            echo "<td></td>";
            echo "<td></td>";
            echo "<td></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

                $p_id = $row["p_id"];
                $uid = $row["user_id"];
                $firstname = $row["firstname"];
                $lastname = $row["lastname"];
                $title = $row["title"];
                $description = $row["description"];
                $p_hospital = $row["p_hospital"];
                $approved = $row["approved"];

                if($_GET['order'] == "submitter"){
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>$firstname $lastname</td>";
                    echo "<td>$p_hospital</td>";
                    echo "<td>$description</td>";
                    echo "<td>";
                    echo ($approved == "Yes") ? "<img src='imgs/check.png' />" : "<img src='imgs/pending.png' />" ;
                    echo "</td>";
                    echo "<td>$title</td>";
                    echo "<td><a href='details.php?p_id=$p_id'>View</a><br /></td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }else if($_GET['order'] == "hospital"){
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>$p_hospital</td>";
                    echo "<td>$description</td>";
                    echo "<td>";
                    echo ($approved == "Yes") ? "<img src='imgs/check.png' />" : "<img src='imgs/pending.png' />" ;
                    echo "</td>";
                    echo "<td>$title</td>";
                    echo "<td>$firstname $lastname</td>";
                    echo "<td><a href='details.php?p_id=$p_id'>View</a><br /></td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }else if($_GET['order'] == "keywords"){
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>$description</td>";
                    echo "<td>";
                    echo ($approved == "Yes") ? "<img src='imgs/check.png' />" : "<img src='imgs/pending.png' />" ;
                    echo "</td>";
                    echo "<td>$title</td>";
                    echo "<td>$firstname $lastname</td>";
                    echo "<td>$p_hospital</td>";
                    echo "<td><a href='details.php?p_id=$p_id'>View</a><br /></td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }else if($_GET['order'] == "status"){
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>";
                    echo ($approved == "Yes") ? "<img src='imgs/check.png' />" : "<img src='imgs/pending.png' />" ;
                    echo "</td>";
                    echo "<td>$title</td>";
                    echo "<td>$firstname $lastname</td>";
                    echo "<td>$p_hospital</td>";
                    echo "<td>$description</td>";
                    echo "<td><a href='details.php?p_id=$p_id'>View</a><br /></td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }else{
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>$title</td>";
                    echo "<td>$firstname $lastname</td>";
                    echo "<td>$p_hospital</td>";
                    echo "<td>$description</td>";
                    echo "<td>";
                    echo ($approved == "Yes") ? "<img src='imgs/check.png' />" : "<img src='imgs/pending.png' />" ;
                    echo "</td>";
                    echo "<td><a href='details.php?p_id=$p_id'>View</a><br /></td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
            } 

    } 
}
```

Comment: You're expected to do *some* work yourself. Remove parts of the query that do not appear to be relevant. Tell us what **broken my function** means - no results, unexpected results, an error message? (hint: error messages might be useful for others trying to help you)

Answer (score 4):

First of all, your code looks like an [SQL injection attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) waiting to happen.  If you must build SQL queries by hand like this, at least use [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) on your input variables.

Once you've taken care of that, take the `ORDER BY project.p_id DESC` out of the initial part of the query, and add

```
$q .= " ORDER BY project.p_id DESC ";
```

just before the line

```
$result = mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());
```

That way, the `ORDER BY` clause will be at the end of the query, where it belongs.

Comment: +1 for hinting SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: This answer was perfect and my page now works.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Your code adds additional `WHERE` clauses to the query in variable y. This works if q ends with a `WHERE` clause, but this does not work if q ends with an `ORDER BY`. What you have to do is make sure the `ORDER BY` is after all `WHERE` clauses.

Answer (score 0):

The **ORDER BY** keyword is used to sort the result-set. **project.p_id DESC** is not a part of your result-set. 
It needs to be

```
SELECT user_info.column_name,....,project.p_id FROM user_info ........
```

Comment: `ORDER BY` will work whether the field is in the `SELECT` or not.

Comment: It worked with only the steps from Ilmari Karonen, but thank you anyway.